# How to get the sum of a field based on a date field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry, if the title does not do this question justice, but please recommend a new title, if you have a better one.

What i need to accomplish is i need to take QtyOnHand (for a given AffectedDate) / sum(IssQty) based on a range between RecDates. So if the AffectedDate = '2015-2' then i want to sum all of the IssQty where RecDate is between '2014-2' and '2015-1'. I want this type of formula for every  AffectedDate row. So it can calculate on the fly, meaning it will always take the AffectedDates year and month and - 12 and then sum together the IssQty, based on the RecDate. Here are some Examples.

```
ItemKey RecDate IssQty  AffectedDate    QtyOnHand
20406   2014-1   751.898       2014-1           842.132
20406   2014-2   744.102       2014-2           539.03
20406   2014-5   493.847       2014-5           486.183
20406   2014-7   494.834      2014-7            1314.209
20406   2014-8   494.217       2014-8           819.992
20406   2014-9   741.017       2014-9          1401.975
20406   2014-10  889.714       2014-10         512.261
20406   2014-12  740.647       2014-12        640.19
20406   2015-2   496.068       2015-2         144.122
20406   2015-3   496.068       2015-3         530.054
20406   2015-5   370.941       2015-5        159.113
20406   2015-7   989.668       2015-7        492.19
20406   2015-8   792.228       2015-8        890.662
20406   2015-9   744.102       2015-9        1028.56
```

1. AffectedDate = '2015-3' so take the QtyOnHand for that AffectedDate [530.054] /  Sum(IssQty) between the RecDate of '2014-03' and '2015-02'
2. AffectedDate = '2015-5' so take the QtyOnHand for that AffectedDate [159.113] /  Sum(IssQty) between the RecDate of '2014-05' and '2015-04'

These are examples of how i want this formula to work.

Comment: What have you tried? This could be done very easily with joins or cross applies based on date.

Comment: I assume it has to be 2008 T-SQL? This is almost trivial in 2012+, provided you have an entry for every month the (I note that 2015-1 and 2015-4 are missing, for example, is that intentional?).

Comment: `2014-1` is NOT a date.

Comment: this is not T-SQL, this is a view i am trying to create. I do have an entry for every month and those dates are missing because there is no data for those dates (2015-1 and 2015-4). I have tried a case statement, but i believe my formula is off, as it keeps returning a 0 values. @Larnu

Comment: @ZLK i have joined the two views i am using as the AffectedDate and QtyOnHand come from one table and RecDate and IssQty come from another table. i tried to do a case statement, but i am not sure what i am doing wrong. can you help?

Comment: You're not using T-SQL? So you aren't using SQL Server? Which RDBMS are you using then? The only query language you can use with SQL Server is T-SQL, so if that's not what you're using, you must be using a different one. Could you update your tags accordingly please?

Comment: @Larnu i am using MSSQL, but T-SQL is the language when writing a Stored procedure, where here i am creating a view.

Comment: Err...? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql **Everything** you write in SQL Server is T-SQL, whether it be a simple `SELECT`, creating a `VIEW`, a `TABLE`, a udf, an sp, a user defined data type, or anything else you can think of. So, back to my initial question, does this have to be 2008? You have access to `ROWS BETWEEN` in 2012+.

Comment: @Laru yes i am using MSSQL 2017. I am sorry i was unaware of that. So yes, i am using T-SQL.

Comment: Ok, there's a big difference between 2008 and 2017, and you tagged 2008. You might want to update that tag. :)

Comment: @Larnu, yea i just assumed that it was 2008 >, but i just updated. Any chance you can help me with this, as it is a lingering problem that for some reason, as basic as it may be, i am having trouble solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's start at the basics first. Like Mr Bertrand said `2014-1` is not a date, it's a varchar that looks like you're saying "2014 minus 1" (which is 2013). I assume that what it's really meant to represent is the 1st month of 2014, however, if you want to store dates, store them as a `date`. you'll note that `CONVERT(date,'2014-1`) will fail.

I'm not going to cover converting these values to dates, but i have HAD to do it in my sample data; maybe that'll help you.

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (ItemKey int,
                      RecDate date, --The source data is not a date
                      IssQty decimal(10,3),
                      AffectedDate date, --The sourse data is not a date
                      QtyOnHand decimal(10,3));
INSERT INTO #Sample
SELECT ItemKey,
       CONVERT(date,CASE LEN(RecDate) WHEN 6 THEN STUFF(RecDate,5,1,'0') + '01'
                                      WHEN 7 THEN REPLACE(RecDate,'-','') + '01' END),
       IssQty,
       CONVERT(date,CASE LEN(AffectedDate) WHEN 6 THEN STUFF(AffectedDate,5,1,'0') + '01'
                                           WHEN 7 THEN REPLACE(AffectedDate,'-','') + '01' END),
       QtyOnHand
FROM (VALUES (20406,'2014-1',751.898,'2014-1',842.132  ),
             (20406,'2014-2',744.102,'2014-2',539.03   ),
             (20406,'2014-5',493.847,'2014-5',486.183  ),
             (20406,'2014-7',494.834,'2014-7',1314.209 ),
             (20406,'2014-8',494.217,'2014-8',819.992  ),
             (20406,'2014-9',741.017,'2014-9',1401.975 ),
             (20406,'2014-10',889.714,'2014-10',512.261),
             (20406,'2014-12',740.647,'2014-12',640.19 ),
             (20406,'2015-2',496.068,'2015-2',144.122  ),
             (20406,'2015-3',496.068,'2015-3',530.054  ),
             (20406,'2015-5',370.941,'2015-5',159.113  ),
             (20406,'2015-7',989.668,'2015-7',492.19   ),
             (20406,'2015-8',792.228,'2015-8',890.662  ),
             (20406,'2015-9',744.102,'2015-9',1028.56  )) V(ItemKey, RecDate, IssQty, AffectedDate, QtyOnHand);
```

Next, we're missing some months here, which is a problem, as you want the last 12 months of data. Thus we need to fill those in. I'll be using a Calendar table (you'll need to Google this, mine his called DimDate here).

Then, because we have a record for every row, we can use `ROWS BETWEEN` resulting in:

```
WITH MaxMin AS(
    SELECT ItemKey, MIN(AffectedDate) AS MinDate, MAX(AffectedDate) AS MaxDate
    FROM #Sample
    GROUP BY ItemKey),
WithNewColumn AS(
    SELECT MM.ItemKey,
           S.RecDate,
           S.IssQty,
           DD.[Date] AS AffectedDate,
           S.QtyOnHand,
           S.QtyOnHand / SUM(S.IssQty) OVER (PARTITION By MM.ItemKey ORDER BY DD.[Date]
                                             ROWS BETWEEN 13 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS YourNewColumn
    FROM MaxMin MM
         JOIN DimDate DD ON DD.[Date] BETWEEN MM.MinDate AND MM.MaxDate AND DD.[Calendar Day] = 1
         LEFT JOIN #Sample S ON MM.ItemKey = S.ItemKey
                            AND DD.[Date] = S.AffectedDate)
SELECT *
FROM WithNewColumn
WHERE RecDate IS NOT NULL --eliminate the NULLs (if you want to). if not, this isn't needed, nor the CTE above
ORDER BY ItemKey, AffectedDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your issue with only one `sum` window function if you did not have gaps in your dates. So you need self join. Here is one option using `apply`

```
select 
    *, a.QtyOnHand / c.total
from 
    myTable a
    outer apply (
        select
            total = sum(IssQty)
        from
            myTable b
        where
            b.RecDate between dateadd(mm, -12, a.AffectedDate) and dateadd(mm, -1, a.AffectedDate)
    ) c
```